# How to check for row existence to before merging datasets (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, exists

I am trying to merge two datasets and would like to check if a row already exists on one of the tables.

Here I'd like to select everything from `table_1` that's not already on `table_2` matching on 3 column values.

**Table 1**

```
| id | key   | value   |
|----|-------|---------| 
| 1  | brand | alpha   |
| 1  | color | red     |
| 2  | brand | charlie |
```

**Table 2**

```
| id | key   | value   |
|----|-------|---------| 
| 2  | brand | charlie |
| 2  | color | yellow  |
```

**Desired Output**

```
| id | key   | value   |
|----|-------|---------| 
| 2  | color | yellow  |
```

**Query**

```
select [id], [key], [value]
from db..table_1
where not exists (
  select
  [id], [key], [value]
  from db..table_2
)
```

How can I achieve this in SQL server?

Comment: Do you consider a "duplicate" row as one with the same `id`, the same `key`, the same `id + key`, or the same `id + key + value`? I feel like if those are your real column names they make it very difficult how you uniquely identify a row. Perhaps you could provide some sample data from both tables, with edge cases (like same id and same key but different value), and indicate which rows from b you want excluded?

Comment: Yes, duplicate matching on all 3 columns. Sample data has been added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many ways, but I imagine this answer will have to change, because based on the column names I think your requirement is ambiguous. These are three *different* ways to do it, but the output might be different if, for example, there are duplicates *already present* in t1.

```
-- except
SELECT [id], [key], [value] FROM dbo.table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT [id], [key], [value] FROM dbo.table_2;

-- not exists (must be correlated to t1!)
SELECT [id], [key], [value] 
FROM dbo.table_1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table_2 AS t2
    WHERE t2.[id]    = t1.[id]
      AND t2.[key]   = t1.[key]
      AND t2.[value] = t1.[value]
);

-- left outer join    
SELECT t1.[id], t1.[key], t1.[value]
  FROM dbo.table_1 AS t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table_2 AS t2
       ON t2.[id]    = t1.[id]
      AND t2.[key]   = t1.[key]
      AND t2.[value] = t1.[value]
 WHERE t2.[id] IS NULL;
```

Some [performance aspects here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

If you have different collations between tables, you can resolve the conflict using the `COLLATE` clause, but you need to be sure you are mapping to the right collation to compare values the way you expect (keeping in mind that if you map to a case-sensitive or binary collation, `banana` <> `BANANA`).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1(a nvarchar(32) COLLATE Slovenian_BIN);

CREATE TABLE dbo.t2(a nvarchar(32) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS);

SELECT a FROM dbo.t1 
EXCEPT 
SELECT a COLLATE Slovenian_BIN FROM dbo.t2;
         ---------------------
```

Comment: Is there a workaround for except when the tables have different collations?

Comment: @Matthew Sure, you can add a `COLLATE` clause to each string-based column in t2 so that they match t1, but note that that may make things that you think should match no longer match (e.g. case sensitive or binary collation, do you want `banana` = `BananA`, or no?).

Comment: Working through this now... Is this two solutions? One with `except` and one with a `where not exists`? These are each returning lists of different lengths... and the second seems to error out on `ambiguous column name`.

Comment: @Matthew Three different ways that you can test (since they may perform differently depending on types / schema / indexes).